# Where is the configuration file which keeps info about mount shares

Tags: 18.04, mount

In Ubuntu 18.04 I set up a share for Box.com and after doing so, I realised it was not the account I actually required (I have 2 accounts).

So, in Files, I selected Remove (but not before I had entered the username and password and selected remember for ever).

Prior to this, a `sudo mount -a`command in terminal did not give any errors. However, after removing the Box drive I now get `Error (112) Host is Down` message after `sudo mount -a`but rebooting the system does not complain about the missing drive (unless mount -a is issued).

Is there a configuration file somewhere where I can remove/modify the Box.com drive specification?

I have looked in fstab but there is no entry which relates to Box.

Comment: Given that this is paid software, I think you will find a lack of general support here.  Their website does not seem to contain download and installation instructions, but then again, you might find a lot more support of the [Box community forms](https://community.box.com/t5/All-Forums/ct-p/Forums)

Comment: Paid software? Ubuntu is free and there was no charge for the Box accounts... My question is less about Box but more about Ubuntu and finding the place in Ubuntu where I can get shot of the mount for good.

Comment: If I go to [https://www.box.com/pricing](https://www.box.com/pricing), the minimum rate seems to be $5.00 per user, per month.  The sounds like "paid software" to me...  AFAIK all of the normal mounts are in `/etc/fstab`, but I would assume that any program with root privileges can add a mount.